# Replace 1st Occurence line with Value1 and 2nd Occurence line with Value2 using sed

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm stuck with requirement where I have to replace first occurrence keyword{as well as whole line} with value x and 2nd occurrence with value Y. For example

1. sudo docker push IP:PORT/ABC:1
2. sudo docker push IP:PORT/XYZ:1

In above case, I would select using keyword "sudo docker push" and replace 1st occurrence whole line with `sudo docker push IP1:PORT/ABC:1` and 2nd occurrence whole line with `sudo docker push IP2:PORT/ABC:1`.

I have tried following combinations but nothing has worked until now :

```
sed -i "s,old-word,new-word," file-name
sed -i "<occurence-number> s,old-word,new-word,g" file-name
sed -i " s,old-word,new-word,<occurence-number>g" file-name
sed "<occurence-number>,old-word,{s,old-word,new-word,}" file-name
```

Comment: What exactly output of your input strings? your question is a little unclear.

Comment: What does mean first and second occurence? Two different strings? One line
Kindly provide more clear examples

Comment: In simplest word, I want to replace whole row wherever "old-text" occurs first time  with Value1 and on second occurrence whole row with Value2. Hope that it simplifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow me to rephrase your question:

The file named `file-name` containing v.gr.

```
some lines
...
sudo docker push IP:PORT/ABC:1
more lines
...
sudo docker push IP:PORT/ABC:1
and so on
...
```

must be changed into:

```
some lines
...
sudo docker push IP1:PORT/ABC:1
more lines
...
sudo docker push IP2:PORT/ABC:1
and so on
...
```

The difficulty is that two occurences of the same key must trigger two different changes.

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

key="sudo docker push"
#Caution: "/" inside the two strings below must be escaped as "\/"
change1="sudo docker push IP1:PORT\/ABC:1"
change2="sudo docker push IP2:PORT\/ABC:1"

sed -i "
  0,/$key/s/^.*$key.*$/FIRST-OCCURENCE/
  0,/$key/s/^.*$key.*$/$change2/
  /FIRST-OCCURENCE/s//$change1/
" file-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Example is not clear... it will be better to provide full string example of what you have and what you want in the result.
But maybe you are looking for "sudo docker push" and trying to replace only this part, instead of whole line.
You can use regexp to select rest of line, like that:

```
sed -i 's/sudo docker push.*/sudo docker push IP:PORT/XYZ:1/'
```

Or just provide more clear example of origin and result strings.

Comment: Yeah, the question could have been better, but I found following two parts pretty clear **(1)** »*replace first occurrence [...] with value x and 2nd occurrence with value Y.*« This seems to be missing in your answer. **(2)** »*replace [...] keyword {as well as whole line}*« or »*replace [...] occurrence whole line*« pretty clearly indicate that OP wants to do the opposite of »*replace only this part, instead of whole line*«.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with `sed`, but very inconvenient:

```
sed '/OLD/{s|.*|NEW-1|; :label; n; /OLD/s|.*|NEW-2|; b label;}'
```

Depending on your version of `sed`, you might have to replace the `;` after `:label` and `b label` with a literal linebreak to make this work.

For the input …

```
a b c
d OLD e
f g h
i OLD k
l m n
```

… this prints …

```
a b c
NEW-1
f g h
NEW-2
l m n
```

For simplicity, you might want to use `awk` instead:

```
awk '/OLD/ {++c; if (c==1) {$0="NEW-1"} else {$0="NEW-2"}} 1'
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN {a[1]="NEW-1"; a[2]="NEW-2"} /OLD/ {$0=a[++c]} 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sh
sed -i "/old-word/c new-word" file-name
```

Comment: Quote from the question, emphasis mine: »*replace first occurrence [...] with value x and **2nd occurrence with value Y**.*«